# How do I change the ingame popupmenu in counterstrike 1.6?

Tags: pc, windows-7, counter-strike-condition-zero

After going to a public server my game client downloaded a fiew files and since that moment it seems that the ingame popup menu (that opens when you press "H" and contains options like changing between left and right hand etc.) is completely changed. Instead of the standard options I only got options for adding or removing bots. Is there a way to change that menu (like the menu on the startscreen)?

PS: I know I could just try to uninstall and install again but i'd like to avoid that if possible.